# Configuring own backup sbs server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, windows-sbs-2008

We are running windows small business server 2008 but when it comes back every day with its status report it is reporting the backup as not configured. is there a way to tell windows that we are using our own backup software like you tell windows you are managing the firewall/antivirus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-server-sbs/72687/Eliminating-Backup-Not-Configured-error) should stop the warning message.

Specifically:

> Run the SBS Backup wizard, and elect
>   to 'not use SBS Backup'. From the
>   Welcome screen, next > What you see
>   next I think depends on whether you've
>   run the backup wizard  before, or not.
>   Here's what I see (as I've run the
>   wizard previously). Modify Backup
>   Settings - there is a  "change
>   existing backup settings" or a  "do
>   not use SBS backup" radio button.